# Resolving indeterminacy of map on projective spaces induced by a linear map

Tags: algebraic-geometry, blowup, pullback, hilbert-polynomial

Let $V$ and $W$ be two $k$-vector spaces, where $k$ can be assumed as $\mathbb{C}$, and 
$f:V\longrightarrow W$ a non null $k$-linear map with kernel $K$. The map $f$ naturally induces a rational morphism $F:\mathbb{P}(V)\dashrightarrow\mathbb{P}(W)$, where $F$ is defined in the non-empty open set $\mathbb{P}(V)\backslash\mathbb{P}(K)$. Then via blowing up we resolve the map 
$F$, that is. Let $\pi: Bl_{\mathbb{P}(K)}(\mathbb{P}(V))\longrightarrow\mathbb{P}(V)$ be the blow up of $\mathbb{P}(V)$ along $\mathbb{P}(K)$, and $F':Bl_{\mathbb{P}(K)}(\mathbb{P}(V))\longrightarrow\mathbb{P}(W)$ be the map which resolves $F$ or more precisely $F = F'\circ\pi$.

I would like to know two things and any help by indicating books, solution any hint would let me happy.

1 - Is it simple to know what is the blow up in this specific case?

2- What is the pull back $(F')^*\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}(W)}(1)$?

Thank you so much for any help!!

Comment: Here's one method of attack: reduce to the case where $V=k^n$ and $W=k^m$ with $m\leq n$ and $f$ is a coordinate projection. Then you ought to be able to compute directly with the equations defining a blowup. This should be fairly straightforwards and I encourage you to try it and add your attempt to the question if you run in to difficulties.

Comment: @KReiser I am working on it. Thank you so much for your help. And when I finish, or not, I will let you know. Again thank you!

Comment: @KReiser I've tried to follow your tip. Since you said to add my attempt I did it. Could you please have a look at it to say if I understand your hint?

Comment: @KReiser since you has a very good reputation could you see the continuation of this problem here https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3720981/518000 maybe you could help me with other hint? THANK YOU A LOT!

Answer (score 1):

Let me assume $f$ is surjective (otherwise, replace $W$ by $Im(f)$). Then
$$
Bl_{\mathbb{P}(K)}(\mathbb{P}(V)) = 
\mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{P}(W)}(K \otimes \mathcal{O} \oplus \mathcal{O}(-1)).
$$
Next, if $H_V$ and $H_W$ are the pullbacks of the hyperplane classes of $\mathbb{P}(V)$ and $\mathbb{P}(W)$, respectively, and $E$ is the exceptional divisor of the blowup, then
$$
H_W = H_V - E.
$$

Comment: I found quite difficult to understand your solution. Although your answer is very elegant , it is so short that I had some troubles to understand. But by what I understand it is essential what I did following the hint of KReiser. Could please give a look, I **really would like to accept your answer**. Thak you for your help!!

Comment: Dear Sasha, I can see the blowup is a projective bundle of rank $k$ over $\mathbb P(W)$, where $k=\dim(K)$, with fiber at $p$ the proper transform of projective $k$-plane spanned by $\mathbb P(K)$ and $p$, but why is this projective bundle the projectivization of $\mathcal{O}^{\oplus k}\oplus \mathcal{O}(-1)$ as you claimed?

Comment: @AGlearner: For instance, choose a splitting $V = K \oplus W$, then there is a natural embedding $K \otimes \mathcal{O} \oplus \mathcal{O}(-1) \to K \otimes \mathcal{O} \oplus W \otimes \mathcal{O} = V \otimes \mathcal{O}$, which induces a morphism of this projective bundle to $\mathbb{P}(V)$. Now you can check that this morphism is the blowup.

Answer (score 1):

Here I use the tip ginven by @KReiser as an attempt of answer.

Let $p:\mathbb{P}^r\dashrightarrow\mathbb{P}^{r-k-1}$ with $0\le k<r$ be the projection
$(a_0:\cdots:a_r)\longmapsto (a_{r-k}:\cdots:a_r)$. Such a rational map has base $K:=V(X_0,\cdots,X_k)\subsetneq\mathbb{P}^r$, that is, the domain of $p$ is $\mathbb{P}^r\backslash K$. The blow-up, $X:=Bl_{K}(\mathbb{P}^r)$, of $\mathbb{P}^r$ along of $K$ is
\begin{eqnarray}
  X &\overset{\pi}{\longrightarrow}& \mathbb{P}^r\\
  ((a_0:\cdots:a_r),(b_{k+1}:\cdots:b_r)) &\longmapsto& (a_0:\cdots:a_r),
\end{eqnarray}
where $X=V(X_iY_j-X_jY_i\mid k+1\leq i,j,\le r)\subset \mathbb{P}^r\times\mathbb{P}^{r-k-1}$, here we have given homogeneous coordinates $X_i$ to $\mathbb{P}^r$ and $Y_i$ to $\mathbb{P}^{r-k-1}$.
The morphim
\begin{eqnarray}
  X &\overset{P}{\longrightarrow}& \mathbb{P}^{r-k-1}\\
  ((a_0:\cdots:a_r),(b_{k+1}:\cdots:b_r)) &\longmapsto& (b_{k+1}:\cdots:b_r),
\end{eqnarray}
resolves $p$, i.e, $p\circ\pi=P$. To see this, consider the open sets
$$
U_i=\{Y_i\neq0,X_i\neq0\}\subsetneq X \mbox{ for } i=k+1,\cdots,r
$$
In $U_i$ we have $ X_j=X_iY_j$ with $j=k+1,\cdots,r$. Then $p\circ\pi|_{U_i}$ is given by
\begin{eqnarray}
  p\circ\pi((x_0:\cdots:x_k:x_iy_{k+1}:\cdots:x_iy_r),(y_{k+1}:\cdots:y_r))
  &=& p((x_0:\cdots:x_k:x_iy_{k+1}:\cdots:x_iy_r)) \\
  &=&(x_iy_{k+1}:\cdots:x_iy_r)\\
  &=&(y_{k+1}:\cdots:y_r).
\end{eqnarray}
Which shows that $P|_{U_i}=p\circ\pi|_{U_i}$ for all $i=k+1,\cdots,r$. From this last expression we see that actually $P|_{U'_i}=p\circ\pi|_{U'_i}$ where $U_i\subsetneq U'_i:=\{Y_i\neq0\}$. But the $U'_i$ is a cover of $X$, which shows that $P=p\circ\pi$.

The exceptional divisor is given by $E=\pi^{-1}(K)=V(X_{k+1},\cdots,X_r)\subsetneq X$. We have a canonical immersion
$(\pi,P): X \hookrightarrow\mathbb{P}^r\times\mathbb{P}^{r-k-1}$ which give us
$P^*\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{r-k-1}}(1)=\pi^*\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^r}(1)\otimes\mathcal{O}_{X}(-E)$.

Comment: In your last paragraph, it should be $P=p\circ \pi$ as morphisms, otherwise $P\circ \pi^{-1}=p$ does not make sense to me becase the left hand side is not a well-defined morphism.

Comment: @AGlearner you're right, I've written $P\circ \pi^{-1}=p$ to mean that the agree in the domain of definition of the birational map $\pi$. But I need to verify that we have a well defined morphism $P=p\circ\pi$ indeed. Thank you so much for your comment!

Comment: modification done @AGlearner, thank you for your observation!